# NGINX Cache Key Control: including HTTP Headers

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup NGINX as an HTTP cache in front of a webserver and found this great guide: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/.

It seems to be possible to modify the cache key from the [default](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key), but looking through the [list of variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), I don't see any way to include specific HTTP Headers in the key. I know NGINX supports the Vary header which is exactly the behavior I want here, but the webserver doesn't currently set any Cache-Control headers.

Answer (score 1):

What you’re looking for is [`$http_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_), where *name* should be replaced with your request header’s name in lowercase and dashes replaced by underscores. For example, the `Accept-Language` header corresponds with `$http_accept_language`.

You can append the default cache key like this:

```
proxy_cache_key “$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri$http_accept_language”;
```

Nota bene - headers with underscores aren’t supported by default. To access those run `underscores_in_headers on;`.